# NSURL with special characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

How can I encode this url to be displayed in a UIWebview:

[http://de.wikipedia.org/?search=Bevölkerungsentwicklung](http://de.wikipedia.org/?search=Bev%C3%B6lkerungsentwicklung)

I tried:

```
-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding
-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
```

and

```
CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                        (CFStringRef)mobileUrl,
                                        NULL,
                                        (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

thanks

joerg

Answer (score 8):

Encode just the search part of the URL string:

```
// searchString is the unescaped search string, e.g., "Bevölkerungsentwicklung"

NSString *encodedSearchString = [searchString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://de.wikipedia.org/?search=%@", encodedSearchString];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

(Note as well that NSUTF8StringEncoding is the encoding used.)

Comment: ok this could be an approach but I'm not sure the url will always look like that. Could also be:
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bevölkerungsentwicklung

Comment: @Joerg: Sorry; I assumed the search term was user-input. :S

Comment: `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is deprecated: Use `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(_:)` instead, which always uses the recommended UTF-8 encoding, and which encodes for a specific URL component or subcomponent since each URL component or subcomponent has different rules for what characters are valid.

Comment: That method didn't exist when this question was answered, but that's now correct.

Answer (score 2):

Just use below sample code;

```
NSString *urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://de.wikipedia.org/?search=%@", searchString];
NSString *encodedString = [urlstring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
```

Comment: hm yes but I'm looking more for a solution to encode any url.
it also could be:
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bevölkerungsentwicklung

Answer (score 1):

I found also that for some North European characters, NSISOLatin1StringEncoding fits better.
This one gives me a better result

```
- (void) testEncoding {
    NSString * urlString = @"http://example/path/fileName_blå.pdf";
    urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);
}
```