# NSURLRequest with url containing special characters

Tags: objective-c, nsurl, nsurlrequest, google-suggest

I'm having the same problem as:
[NSURL with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145846/nsurl-with-special-characters)

But tried their solution. Can't get my NSURLRequest to work with åöä characters. If the variable "string" contains åöä the request return null. Also tried with NSISOLatin1StringEncoding.

```
NSString *encodedString = [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&q=%@", encodedString];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
```

This works: 
http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&q=%C3%A5%C3%B6%C3%A4 (åöä)

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Using the debugger the NSURL looks correct:

```
string  __NSCFString *  @"åäö"  0x0a77cd60
encodedString   __NSCFString *  @"%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6"   0x0a77fc40
url NSURL * @"http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&q=%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6" 0x0a79d1f0
```

**Solved**: The problem was not the NSURL it was how the return NSDATA was interpreted.

Comment: So `urlString` doesn't look like the URL that works?  How does it differ?

Comment: So the URL you produce does work (using Windows/Chrome).  Therefore that code is fine I would say and perhaps your issues lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
```

try using

```
NSString *encoded = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters: [NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: encoded]];
```